# Question on the Introduction of Bourbaki’s Commutative Algebra.

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra

The following is taken from the introduction paragraph of the volume *Commutative Algebra.* The equation mentioned below with $(*)$ is the following:

> Diophantine System $(*)$: $P(x_1,...,x_n)=0$.

[image: Introduction Paragraph]

The part I do not quite understand is the following:

> The original problem (to solve $(*)$ in $\mathbb Z$), thus weakened, is finally transformed into the analogous problem for local rings of the type $A/\mathfrak m^n$.

How is the problem of solving $(*)$ in $\mathbb Z$ weakened into solving in congruences modulo prime powers in $\mathbb Z/p^k\mathbb Z$? And how does solving $(**)$ above give a solution in the completion $\widehat{\mathbb Z}_{(p)}$?

Comment: The completion [is the inverse limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completion_of_a_ring#General_construction) of those quotients. Solving ($**$) is finding what would be the projections to those quotients of solutions in the completion. ($**$) is a weakening of ($*$) in the sense that any solution of ($*$) gives solutions of ($**$) by the quotient maps $\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @conditionalMethod I could be wrong, but I thought the author means that “To solve equation $(*)$ it is sufficient to consider solutions in the local rings $A/\mathfrak m^n$ for every integers $n$”. I’d like to know how this follows by the previous arguments he makes.

Comment: They repeatedly say no. First in "we clearly cannot hope in this way to obtain complete results for the original problem", when referring to reduction modulo $p$. Then "it still does not follow tha tthe system ($*$) has a solution in $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$", when referring to all reductions modulo $p^k$ for all $k$. That is in the quoted text. Maybe somewhere outside they were referring to [Hasse principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_principle).